# how to enable virtual directory in php.ini?

Tags: php

when i do phpinfo() in my localhost it shows "Virtual Directory Support     enabled"

but when i do this in server it shows "Virtual Directory Support    disabled "...how do i enable virtual directory. what do i need to change in php.ini file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got my answer...

"Virtual directories are handled by the server, not by PHP.Look up how to setup virtual directories for the server you are using."