# Issue loading remote PHP app via Virtual Directories in IIS

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

I’m currently running a wordpress IIS server for site hosting (lets call it Web01), then running a separate IIS server for web application hosting. (Apps01)

I’m trying to utilize virtual directories on Web01 to dish out the content provided by Apps01 on my website.

So Apps01 hosts an IIS application called FileRun in an IIS site simply called “FTP”. going to http://localhost shows the application launches properly and I can login and use it just fine.

On Web01, I created a virtual directory under my main web IIS site called “ftp” as well as provided it with proper "connect as" account permissions, performed test to verify successful connections and I can expand and see the virtual directory contents etc.... When I attempt to go to http://www.example.com/ftp from Web01. It loads a page stating “ION Loader is required” however, I already have this ION Loader, loaded on Apps01 and it is functional. (as it is part of the FileRun, install). So at this point I used PHP Manager to redirect Web01 on FTP Virtual Directory to point to PHP content on Apps01 since that is where the program is located. Now I'm receiving an **internal 500 error** when trying to load http://www.example.com/ftp from Web01.

I check the remote PHP servers logs (Apps01) and see the following errors:

> [11-Jan-2018 11:46:58 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\apps01\PHP\v5.6\ext\php_sqlsrv.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>    in Unknown on line 0

It appears to repeat this same error but with all php modules that are trying to be accessed from the remote Web01 server.

Any thoughts? Issues appear to be happening when running php based applications via virtual directories in IIS only. I tested by creating a `test.php` page with simple text. If I go to `example.com/ftp/test.php`, content loads fine. So it appears to be spefically an issue with **PHP** (either something about the UNC path in the VD settings or `php.ini` settings that need to be changed to allow this type of access etc...) I just can't find a clear answer for this issue with online searches.

P.S.
I searched on this site and found someone with a similar issue as me. However, their solution is not a real solution and will not work for me. He stated he simply copied the contents from the remote server onto the local Web server... I need the two servers separate so each can process its own roles independently (aka I need app server to process resources for app usage and web server to process web requests etc...) 
[How to enable the Virtual Directory Support php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415628/how-to-enable-the-virtual-directory-support-php)